# Today suddenly: Java live reload unavailable

Tags: vaadin

I had been happily using Java live reload while debugging my Vaadin application over the past few months.

Today, after I started my browser and directed it to my locally running Vaadin application I got a popup in the lower right corner stating:

`Java live reload unavailable. Live reload for Java changes is currently not set up.  Find out how to make use of this functionality to boost your workflow.  Read more`

Clicking onto the `read more` link (pointing to 'https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/workflow/workflow-overview') just brings me to a "404 Page Not Found" error page.

So - two or actually three questions:

1. what could cause my live-reload functionality go missing? I am using MS Edge and the Live-reload plugin *is* enabled (and it used to work until yesterday).
2. where has the page gone explaining how to set that up?
3. and finally: Any idea, what to check or fix to get this working again? I consider that pretty essential functionality for efficient UI development!

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot and in that case do you have spring boot devtools in use? Does the server log tell you anything more? Does the browser log tell you anything more?

Comment: Did you happen to update anything else at the same time? E.g. TravaOpenJDK changed the HotswapAgent support default to disabled in 11.0.9 https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-11-dcevm/releases/tag/dcevm-11.0.9%2B1

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, you can find the documentation here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/live-reload